# How can I show $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$?

Tags: functions, summation, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$$ using the Taylor series.

I tried to do it by first expanding a general formula $$f(g(x)) = f(g(a)) + xg'(a)f'(g(a)) +\frac{1}{2}x^2(g'(a)^2f''(g(a)+ g''(a) f'(g(a))) + HOT $$

Taking $ f(x) = \sin x$ and $ g(x) = kx$ and expanding around a=0,

$ \sin(kx) = kx - \frac{(kx)^3}{3!} + \frac{(kx)^5}{5!}..$

Now, from here is there any way I could arrive at the formula in question?

Comment: That's not true. Let $x = 0$, and $\text{LHS} = 0$ but $\text{RHS} = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: You need to sum over $k$, but as $k$ increases your HOT become less and less negligible.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{\infty}}\frac{\sin kx}{k}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ for $\color{red}{0<x<2\pi}$ is (well, can be) shown using the Taylor series $-\log(1-z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k/k$ (at $z=re^{ix}$ and $r\to 1^-$ using Abel's theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Note, for $x \in (0,2\pi)$,

\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kx )}{k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikx }-e^{-ikx}}{2ik}
=\frac{\ln (1-e^{-ix})- \ln(1-e^{ix}) }{2i}\\
& =\frac1{2i}\ln \frac{1-e^{-ix }}{1-e^{ix}} 
=\frac1{2i}\ln e^{i (\pi-x)}
=\frac{\pi-x}{2}\\
\end{align}

Comment: how did u go from $ \ln \frac{1 - e^{-ix} }{1 - e^{ix} }$ into the nxt step

Comment: @DDD4C4U - $\frac{1-e^{-ix }}{1-e^{ix}} = -e^{-ix }\frac{1-e^{ix }}{1-e^{ix}} = e^{i \pi}e^{-ix }$

Answer (score 2):

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin kx}{k}=\Im\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}}{k}=-\Im \left( \ln(1-e^{ix})\right)=-\Im[\ln [1-\cos x)+i\sin x]$$ $$=-\Im \left[\ln(2-2\cos x)+i\tan^{-1} \frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}\right]=-\tan^{-1}\cot(x/2)=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}.$$Here we have used :$-\ln (1-x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}$ and $\ln (x+iy)= \ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+i\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}.$

Comment: crazy method! +1

Comment: can you explain how you went from ln(1-cosx) + i sinx  into the thing in next step

Comment: @DDD4C4U There,  I have given the formula: $\ln(x+iy)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)+i\tan^{-1}(y/x)$

Comment: how do I proof that?

Comment: $z=x+iy=re^{i\theta} \implies \ln z=\ln r+i \theta, r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \theta -\tan^{-1} (y/x).$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\left.\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{kx} \over k}
\,\right\vert_{\ x\ \not=\ 0} & =
x\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\mrm{sinc}\pars{k\verts{x}} =
-x + x\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\mrm{sinc}\pars{k\verts{x}}
\end{align}
In using the [Abel-Plana Formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E2), we have to ensure that
\begin{align}
0 & = \lim_{\large\verts{k_{y}} \to \infty}
\braces{\mrm{sinc}\pars{\bracks{k_{x} + \ic k_{y}}\verts{x}}
\expo{\large -2\pi\verts{k_{y}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\exp\pars{-\ic\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k_{y}}k_{x}\verts{x}}
\over 2\verts{x}}
\lim_{\large\verts{k_{y}} \to \infty}{\exp\pars{-\bracks{2\pi - \verts{x}}\verts{k_{y}}} \over \verts{k_{y}}}
\end{align}
which *is true* whenever $\ds{\color{red}{\verts{x} < 2\pi}}$.
In such a case,
\begin{align}
\left.\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{kx} \over k}
\,\right\vert_{\ x\ \not=\ 0} & =
-x + x\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\mrm{sinc}\pars{k\verts{x}}
\\[5mm] & =
-x + x\bracks{%
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{sinc}\pars{k\verts{x}}\,\dd k}
_{\ds{\pi \over 2\verts{x}}}\ +\
\left.{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{sinc}\pars{k\verts{x}}\right\vert_{\ k\ =\ 0}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\bracks{\pi\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{x} - x}\,,\quad
0 < \verts{x} < 2\pi} \\ &
\end{align}